# Disable session for one controller Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following question - how can I stop checking the session table for a specific controller. The situation is as follows - I use this package rachidlaasri/laravel-installer, but when I change the SESSION_DRIVER of the database, I get an error "SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sessions'. " this happens because the .env file is changed first and then the migrations are done. My question is, can I stop checking the sessions in the controller running the migrations so they can run without giving the table doesn't exist error?

Comment: Are you running your migrations from a controller?

Comment: Wouldn't you need the session to run so you can check if the user is authorised to access that controller? It sounds like a pretty important controller, one that needs authorisation to access